# Creating a Java String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

**I'm not sure how to get the program to understand there are three different strings in the text file, and how would I add this to my code? I've never created an array before although I'm fairly experienced with creating fun Java programs (like calculators and such) and want to move onto the next step**

I've made a program which does the following:

- Program Functions:
     Asks user to enter a string.
     Asks user to enter a second string which will replace the last two characters of each word of the first string.
     Asks user to enter a third string who's first character will replace every letter "I" of each word of the first string.
  *If the words in the first string are less than two characters and do not include an I- the string will be left alone.

And here is the working code (I'm running with Ready to Program - not sure why the first bit is not included in the code):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class StringModifications

{

 private String input1, input2, input3; // Values only used within this method
    public String information; 

    // Constructor
    public StringModifications ()
    {
        // Initialize class data to 0
        this.input1 = "";
        this.input2 = "";
        this.input3 = "";
    }

    public void setInputStrings (String s1, String s2, String s3)
    {
        // Method to set class data
        this.input1 = s1; // Equal to string 1
        this.input2 = s2;
        this.input3 = s3;
    }

    public String processStrings ()
    {
        StringTokenizer stok = new StringTokenizer (this.input1); // Splits first input string (word by word)
        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer ("");

        String outstring = ""; // Initialize variable to 0

        while (stok.hasMoreTokens () == true) // As long as there are more words in the string:
        {
            String word = stok.nextToken ();
            if (word.length () > 2)
            {

                word = word.substring (0, word.length () - 2); // Removes the last two letters of each word in the first string
                word = word.concat (this.input2); // Adds the second input to the end of the first string

                char letter = input3.charAt (0); // Finds the first letter of the third input
                word = word.replace ('I', letter); // Replaces letter I in first string with first letter of third input
            }


            outstring = outstring + word + " "; // Adds a space between each word when output
        }

        return outstring;
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        String string1, string2, string3;

        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader (  // // Define the input stream reader
                new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        System.out.println ("Enter first string"); // User inputs the first string
        string1 = keyboard.readLine ();

        System.out.println ("Enter second string"); // User inputs the econd string
        string2 = keyboard.readLine ();

        System.out.println ("Enter third string"); // User inputs the third string
        string3 = keyboard.readLine ();

        StringModifications strProc = new StringModifications ();

        strProc.setInputStrings (string1, string2, string3); // Sends values to method (e.g. this.input1 = stirng 1)

         PersonalInfo pi = new PersonalInfo();

        String out = strProc.processStrings (); // String (e.g. this.input1) sent through processStrings method before output

        System.out.println ("Original Input: " + string1); // Displays the original input
        System.out.println ("Modified Input: " + out); // Displays the modified input
    }
}
```

and what I am trying to do is create an array which takes three inputs (Strings, which would be string1, 2 and 3 in the code), as following in the text:
1
hello how are you (string 1)
i am good (string 2)
great (stirng 3)

**I'm not sure how to get the program to understand there are three different strings in the text file, and how would I add this to my code? I've never created an array before although I'm fairly experienced with creating fun Java programs (like calculators and such) and want to move onto the next step**

Answer (score 1):

You use `String[] str = new String[n]` to declare and initialize a new `String` array. This is a static array with a fixed length of `n`, where `n` has to be known during the initialization. Individual elements are accessed through `str[i]`, where `i` is the index of an element from interval `[ 0,n )`.

Example of usage:

```
String[] phrases = new String[3];
phrases[0] = "Hello, how are you?";
phrases[1] = "I am good";
phrases[2] = "Great";

System.out.println("What phrase would you wish to see?");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(phrases[in.nextInt()]);
in.close();
```

If you need a dynamic array with variable number of elements, I would suggest looking into [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class.

Comment: Perhaps add an example of their usage. If I was new, your explanation wouldn't mean much to me.